# Should the client send two different HTTP request for the API if the user wants to execute action on it's profile along with a profile picture

Tags: rest, http, request

At the moment I am designing the backend RESTful API for a web application.
I can't decide whether the API should have only one endpoint for the profile (POST, UPDATE) actions OR one for the properties (name, email, password, etc.) and another for the profile picture.

The reason why I can't decide is that the file upload requires multipart content type while the whole API accepts json content type and I think it can be a little bit anti-pattern to use different content type only for the profile endpoints.

Comment: A file upload is inherently a different content type than json data. This is not an anti pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best practice for this scenario is using 2 API endpoints, but with different design as OP mentioned in the question. The 2 API endpoints include:

1. The API endpoint that accept all image uploading, not just for profile pictures. This endpoint would accept file upload (`Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data`), and return the uploaded file URL to browser.
2. The API endpoint that accept all profile data, including the profile picture URL (achieved from above API endpoint). This endpoint would accept plain text data (`Content-Type` as `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

By this design, the "anti-pattern" problem (use different content type only for the profile endpoints) won't exist, and the API system is still clear and elegant.

Actually, the API design of Stack Overflow on profile editing follow this strategy too: the profile picture is uploaded (through gravatar), and then the generated URL is used in the profile data editing API (`Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).